# Casting to unit-less dtype 'datetime64' is not supported

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a python code which specifies the schema and then creates an empty dataframe.  This python code used to work fine in earlier versions of Pandas and Numpy.  However, with the latest version, it fails.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

schema = {'timestamp': np.datetime64, 'instrument_token': int, 'last_price': float, 'volume': int}
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=schema.keys()).astype(schema)
```

It throws the following error:

> TypeError: Casting to unit-less dtype 'datetime64' is not supported. Pass e.g. 'datetime64[ns]' instead.

I would appreciate if you can help resolve this.

thanks and regards,

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the unit for internal storage ('ns', 'ms', 's', ...):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#                           HERE --v
schema = {'timestamp': 'datetime64[ns]', 'instrument_token': int, 'last_price': float, 'volume': int}
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=schema.keys()).astype(schema)
```

Output:

```
>>> data.dtypes
timestamp           datetime64[ns]
instrument_token             int64
last_price                 float64
volume                       int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: @lenmet. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I have this very same problem and your solution does not work for me. I get the very same 'TypeError: Casting to unit-less dtype 'datetime64' is not supported. Pass e.g. 'datetime64[ns]' instead.' despite having updated the schema accordingly. Something else is wrong here.

Comment: What is your version of Pandas? The code above works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Solved it by downgrading to pandas 1.5.3 version or any version earlier than 2.0.0 . If you are on pandas version 1.5.3, you should see a depreciating warning on this but your code will work. Hope this helps.

```
pip install pandas==1.5.3
```

If you want to make it work on latest pandas version or any version from 2.0.0 onwards, try update the schema to something like this:

```
{'timestamp': 'datetime64[ns]'}
```